# Replacement for GL_SEPARATE_SPECULAR_COLOR and GL_LIGHT_MODEL_COLOR_CONTROL OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to understand some code while I learn OpenGL. I came an across the use of GL_LIGHT_MODEL_COLOR_CONTROL and GL_SEPARATE_SPECULAR_COLOR while trying to compile an open source file but it say's they weren't declared in the scope. I did some searching and found out that they were removed in GL 3.1. I wanted to know what would be a good replacement to use instead of them in this code and what they were meant for.

Comment: You probably should not be grabbing random code off the Internet and trying to learn OpenGL from it. It'd be one thing if it was part of a tutorial, but then the tutorial would explain what it meant and how it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The replacement for them is called "you have to write shaders now". That is, you write the lighting code yourself that gets executed on the GPU.

In [fixed-function lighting model](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline) (which again, no longer exists in [core profile OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context#Context_types)), the diffuse color and the specular color for lights are normally added together per-vertex. So the texture environment only sees a single per-vertex color.

Separating the specular color means that the specular and diffuse colors from the light are separated. So the texture environment sees a pair of colors: one for the diffuse lighting and one for the specular.

The purpose of this is to allow the diffuse lighting to be multiplied by the texture color, then adding the specular color to the result of that. That is, it allows the equation `(T * Diffuse) + Specular` to work. If you don't separate the specular color, then what you have is `T * (Diffuse + Specular)`. This means that the texture color affects the specular highlight as well as the diffuse value. While this is sometimes what you want, you will more often want them to be separate, for the specular highlight to be tinted based on a separate color from the diffuse lighting.